# Enabling SEO Optimizer in Magento 1.7 returns 404 error page on frontend links

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, magento-1.7, php-5.4

After enabling SEO Optimizer in Magento 1.7 my index page works fine, but all links return a 404 error.

My access_log for apache shows:

```
 1.2.3.4 - - [23/Jul/2014:10:32:15 -0400] "GET /~userDir/apparel.html HTTP/1.1" 404 231 "http://192.168.200.26/~userDir/index.php/apparel/shoes/womens/anashria-womens-premier-leather-sandal$
```

Please let me know what other information I can provide to help you help me. I am running the latest version of CentOS, apache, and using PHP 5.4 with the Magento PHP 5.4 patch for Magento 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

My resolution is below. I was a bit lazy about this issue, I apologize.

**Resolution**
Modified Magento's stock .htaccess to fit my URL base.

On line 123 of the .htaccess file you should see:

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
```

For me, this needed to be changed to:

```
RewriteBase /~userDir/
```